# Spacy matcher fails at full stops

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new to spacy and playing around with the following script;

```py
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp  = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "Google announced a new Pixel at Google I/O. The Google I/O is a great place to get all the updates from Google I/O."

def add_event_ent(matcher, doc, i, matches):
    match_id, start, end = matches[i]
    entity = doc[start:end]
    print(entity.text, start, end)

pattern = [[
  {"TEXT": "Google"}, 
  {"TEXT": "I"}, 
  {"TEXT": "/"}, 
  {"TEXT": "O"}, 
  {"IS_PUNCT": True, "OP": "?"}
]]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Google", pattern, on_match = add_event_ent)

doc = nlp(text)
matcher(doc)
```

Output:

```
Google I/O 11 15
[(11578853341595296054, 11, 15)]
```

I would expect this to detect all 3 occurrences of `Google I/O` but it does not and I'm not fully sure why. I tried a few different things but nothing worked, I think the issue is at the full stop.

I wrote what is basically the same code snippet with a different text and pattern:

```py
text = "Hello, World! Hello, World! How are you?"
pattern = [[
  {"LOWER": "hello"},
  {"IS_PUNCT": True},
  {"LOWER": "world"}
]]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Google", pattern, on_match = add_event_ent)
doc = nlp(text)
matcher(doc)
for ent in doc.ents:
  print(f"[ENTITY] {ent.text:{15}} {ent.label_}")
print(doc)
```

Output:

```
Hello, World 0 3
Hello, World 4 7
Hello, World! Hello, World! How are you?
```

Which as you can see did work.

I made [this](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=Google%20announced%20a%20new%20Pixel%20at%20Google%20I%2FO.%20The%20Google%20I%2FO%20is%20a%20great%20place%20to%20get%20all%20the%20updates%20from%20Google%20I%2FO.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1) viz for the first example in case it helps and [this](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=Google%20announced%20a%20new%20Pixel%20at%20Google%20I%2FO.%20The%20Google%20I%2FO%20is%20a%20great%20place%20to%20get%20all%20the%20updates%20from%20Google%20I%2FO.&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22google%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A4%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22i%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A5%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A6%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LOWER%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22o%22%7D%5D%7D%5D) which shows that it does not work but again I am unsure why.

Any help is appreciated and let me know if I can provide more information!

Comment: The issue comes from the tokenization, `O.` has a `.` inside this token.

Comment: Hm I see, that makes sense why it only detects one of the 3. How do I fix that though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the tokenization, `O.` token contains the `.` char at this token text end.

Instead of defining an optional punctuation token in the `pattern` you can match any `O` token with an optional trailing punctuation char. You can use a regex for this:

```py
pattern = [[
  {"TEXT": "Google"}, 
  {"TEXT": "I"}, 
  {"TEXT": "/"}, 
  {"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^O(?:_|[^\w\s])?$"}}
]]
```

Output:

```
Google I/O. 6 10
Google I/O 11 15
Google I/O. 25 29
```

Here, `{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^O(?:_|[^\w\s])?$"}}` will match a token that contains one or two chars, starting with `O` and then containing an optional punctuation char.

- `^` - start of a token (string, in general)
- `O` -  `O` char
- `(?:_|[^\w\s])?` - a `_` or (`|`) any char other than a word and whitespace char (`[^\w\s]`, a negated character class, `\w` stands for letters, digits and underscores and `\s` stands for whitespace), one or zero times (due to `?` quantifier)
- `$` - end of a token (string, in general)